# Go to URL if input val == something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I've found [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zwbRa/5/). In JSFiddle works well, the problem is that, even if I search any != from "advogados" (just testing), the browser goes to: `http://www.site.com/index.html?procura=teste`

No jQuery conflict, no html issue.

Here's JS

```
$("#procura").on("submit", function(event){     

    // prevent form from being truely submitted
    event.preventDefault();

    // get value of text box
    name = $("#procura_texto").val();

    // compare lower case, as you don't know what they will enter into the field.    
    if (name.toLowerCase() == "advogados")
    {
        //redirect the user.. 
        window.location.href = "http://jornalexemplo.com.br/lista%20online/advogados.html";
    }
    else
    {
        alert("no redirect..(entered: " + name + ")");
    }
});
```

Comment: Try instead of `name = $("#procura_texto").val();` use `var name = $("#procura_texto").val();` I am not sure if that would make any difference though..

Comment: try returning false after the if condition.

Comment: JQuery included? Is this script run in a `$(document).ready(function() { })`? How many elements do you have with `id="procura"`? And with `id="procura_texto"`?

Comment: This is extremely annoying. I copy & pasted same code into new JSFiddle (with also jQuery 1.9.1 - same as my live link) and it works in JSFiddle, but not at live site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your javascript is somewhere in your HTML **before** your `<form>` your `$("#procura")` will be an empty set, so the submit-action won't be bound to anything. Try following code:

```
 <html>
     <head>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/your/jquery.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             $(function() {
                 // This code will be run if your document is completely
                 // parsed by the browser, thus all below elements are
                 // accessible

                 $('#procura').on('submit', ....);
             });
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <form id="procura">...</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

`$(function() {})` is also known as `$(document).ready(function() {})`, ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/))

Answer (score 0):

You aren't defining the variable name. http://jsfiddle.net/zwbRa/59/

```
var name = $("#procura_texto").val();
```

Comment: Yes I am! In fact, 7th line of my OS question.

Comment: @user3086817 You're doing it without the `var` keyword. without this it will either define to the global scope or fail. That's the only problem with this question. Look at the fiddle it works.

Comment: `var`keyword? The 7th line it's ok now. In my [live site](http://www.highplay.pt/weber/teste/index.html) the code it's exactly the same